# Replace a string contained in a dictionary that is contained in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

in the scope of one of my programming homework I had to create a kind of battleship game.

One of the instructions whas to create a list that represents the submarines and this list containes each submarine as a dictionary in which the position of the submarine on the board game as well as the health points the submarine.

I also mention that I had to create it with a loop so that the number of submarines can be change at will :

```
nb_subs = 4

submarines = []

for sub_id in range (nb_subs):
    submarines.append({'sub_' + str(sub_id) : {'position':str(rand(0,4)) + str(rand(0,4)) , 'life':2}})
```

This code works properly and as you can see the position is represented by a string such as '00' , '14', etc. so that it can be get back by selecting the index of the string, just like that :

```
submarines[0]['sub_0']['position'][0]
```

This way I just get the "abscissa" of the submarine.

But the point is that I don't know how to modify only the "abscissa" or only the "ordinate" of the submarine's position.

I tried this to modidy the "abscissa" of one of the submarine:

```
submarines[0]['sub_0']['position'][0] = str(int(submarines[0]['sub_0']['position'][0])+1)
```

But I end up having this error message :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-670be0bd7cb8> in <module>()
----> 1 submarines[0]['sub_0']['position'][0] = '5'

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I understand that I could modify the entire string like this :

```
submarines[0]['sub_0']['position'] = '22'
```

But the point is really to get back the element[0] contained in the string corresponding to the keyword 'position'.

Does anyone could help me with that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sounds like you should use a list of integers instead of a string then. `[0, 0]` encodes the position as x, y coordinates, letting you trivially change either. By making them integers you don't have to keep converting between int and str just to increment the number, either.

Comment: This is much more easier ! Thank you !!!